# How can I show datasets in a combobox

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, dataset

Is it possible to show all the data sets that i have in my project/solution in visual studio in a ComboBox? and when i selected the data set i want to show all tables that are in the dataset in  a listbox

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqyUg.png)

Comment: Add the DataSets to a List<DataSet>  or maybe a Dictionary<string, DataSet>so you can use them in a loop..